# Google AppScript large multi-line query string (BigQuery) issue

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-bigquery

I have been perplexed by this issue for a long time. I work with pretty massive multi-line bigquery sql strings. When I go to schedule them using Google AppScript, I have to spend hours trying to format them because:

- They are multi line (~ 1000 lines)
- And to use them in appscript, I have to convert them in a format like this

  `var queryString = "  -- MEASUREMENTS AT DAY LEVEL "
  queryString += "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
  queryString += "-- ** All marketing pages and whether logged in or out "
  queryString += "-- UNION  "
  queryString += "-- All marketing pages irrespective of logged in or out  "
  queryString += "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- "
  queryString += "\n SELECT 'day' as measurement_period,"`

([This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48765771/get-data-from-google-bigquery-by-app-script) question has an example appscript that runs a SQL. That SQL has been formatted to be in one line. In my case it will be multi-line)

Any suggestions how I could possibly avoid this and:
1. Either just copy paste a code block?
2. Or use a "saved query" from my bigquery account?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a view and then just run a query that selects from it as part of the job?

Comment: this one sounds to me as a good answer? unless parameters are involved

Comment: That's what I was hoping to clarify. It may still be possible to use a view if the bulk of the logic doesn't need to be customized, though.

Comment: I am passing in a current date parameter into the query. Would that work with a view? I could possibly get the current date from within the SQL statement of the view and then join or something (or create a temporary variable) to use in the rest of the query.

Comment: Whether you can use views or not depends on your overall query. At which point do you pass the date? You cannot pass parameters in the query that defines the view but if you use them when you then query the view it is feasible. Simple example using bq:
`$ bq mk --use_legacy_sql=false --view 'SELECT word_count FROM 'bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare' WHERE word_count >= 250' [PROJECT_ID]:[DATASET].[VIEW]`
and then
`$ bq query --use_legacy_sql=False --parameter=orderby::word_count 'SELECT * FROM '[PROJECT_ID].[DATASET].[VIEW]' ORDER BY @orderby DESC;`

Comment: @LefterisS I think this is a good solution. I can research on these lines and the cli a bit more and post back a sample which can guide other folks. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the backslash is the line continuation character, so if you end each line with a backslash, that should work to make a really long queryString.

i.e.

var queryString = "SELECT * FROM Foo;\

SELECT * FROM Bar"

There's probably some limit to how long the queryString can be, but I don't know what that is.

Seems like there should be a way to use a saved query, but I have not found it.